# Getting Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in Magento2

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, class

I am getting Fatal error Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /home/sanjeevkahali/public_html/sanjeev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111:

Answer (score 1):

You're missing PHP extension `php-intl` from your server, try to install it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141304)

Comment: @ManashviBirla whats wrong with this? Of course this is an answer.

Comment: Brilliant it's an answer, what do you expected, don't think it's not an answer,